# org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'module-info.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: java, spring, aspect

I build source by using maven. I find Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19, and I can not install property. A error cause is a situation that I develop under proxy environment. But I can not understand how to resolve. Could you give me any advice?
I use the onap/sdc project resource, and I can build without proxy enviroment.

command

```
mvn clean install
```

ajcore.20200114.095601.338.txt

```
---- AspectJ Properties ---
AspectJ Compiler 1.8.6 built on Friday Jun 5, 2015 at 23:41:42 GMT
---- Dump Properties ---
Dump file: ajcore.20200114.095601.338.txt
Dump reason: org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException
Dump on exception: true
Dump at exit condition: abort
---- Exception Information ---
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'module-info.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addAspectsFromJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:260)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:236)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:874)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:249)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
    at com.jcabi.maven.plugin.AjcMojo.executeAJC(AjcMojo.java:239)
    at com.jcabi.maven.plugin.AjcMojo.execute_aroundBody2(AjcMojo.java:218)
    at com.jcabi.maven.plugin.AjcMojo$AjcClosure3.run(AjcMojo.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrap(MethodLogger.java:208)
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$wrap(MethodLogger.java:1)
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrapMethod(MethodLogger.java:164)
    at com.jcabi.maven.plugin.AjcMojo.execute_aroundBody4(AjcMojo.java:203)
    at com.jcabi.maven.plugin.AjcMojo$AjcClosure5.run(AjcMojo.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrapClass(MethodLogger.java:134)
    at com.jcabi.maven.plugin.AjcMojo.execute(AjcMojo.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Parent pom.xml

https://github.com/onap/sdc/blob/master/pom.xml

child pom.xml

https://github.com/onap/sdc/blob/master/catalog-be/pom.xml